# How can I change object material color using time and lerp?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using the following code to change the color over time.

The coloring part is working but it's changing the color too fast. Even if I change the duration value to 5 or 10 it's changing the colors less then a second and it should be 5 seconds. I tried in the Inspector to change the duration to 10 but it didn't effect, still too fast.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;

    private bool scaleUp = false;
    private Coroutine scaleCoroutine;

    public Color startColor;
    public Color endColor;
    public float colorDuration = 5; // duration in seconds

    private float t = 0; // lerp control variable

    private void Start()
    {
        startColor = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        endColor = Color.green;
        objectToScale.transform.localScale = minSize;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            //Flip the scale direction when F key is pressed
            scaleUp = !scaleUp;

            //Stop old coroutine
            if (scaleCoroutine != null)
                StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

            //Scale  up
            if (scaleUp)
            {
                //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
                scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaleOverTime(objectToScale, maxSize, duration));
            }

            //Scale Down
            else
            {
                //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
                scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaleOverTime(objectToScale, minSize, duration));
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            t = 0;
        }
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, t);
        if (t < 1)
        { // while t below the end limit...
          // increment it at the desired rate every update:
            t += Time.deltaTime / duration;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator scaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;

        //Get the current scale of the object to be scaled
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

When I press on C it's changing the colors but too fast.

What I want to do is when i press on C to change slowly and smooth the color of the object.

Comment: Do you mean to use colorDuration instead of duration in the calculation of t?

Comment: @EdMarty right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accumulate the time as it comes and use the accumulated time for the colorLerp method.

The idea is that the t parameter needs to be framed between a *start* and an *end*. The *end* is easy to get: it's the *start* plus the `colorDuration`. We set the *start* at 0 when our "trigger" occurs, in this case when you hit <kbd>C</kbd>.

Each frame brings an increment to our duration, which brings us further away from the *start* (which we refer to "time zero" or `t = 0`), and closer to our *end*, which is `colorDuration`. `t` is simply the ratio of that accumulated time over the maximum time we care about. This way, `t` will change from 0 to 1, which is what's expected by the colour lerping method.

```
private float timeAccumulatorForColor = 0; // Value used as the base for lerping the colour.

// [...]

if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
{
    t = 0;
    timeAcc = 0;
}
if (t < 1)
{ 
  // accumulate the time
  timeAccumulatorForColor += Time.deltaTime; 
  // make sure it's between 0 and the colorDuration (which is our 'end' target)
  timeAccumulatorForColor = Mathf.Clamp(0, colorDuration, timeAcc); 
  // convert it to a ratio properly usable for your colour lerping. 
  t = timeAccumulatorForColor / colorDuration; 
}
```

Comment: Note that I have not tested this code.